# CrispyError : as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field for email field only

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I can't expose Email field from User model in django, If I remove email field from register.html there is no error.
Also if I use {{ form }} It does not show the email field. It shows username, password1 and password2 with no error.

**models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default='default.jpg')
    # FK
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  max_length=10, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= ['username','email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**views.py:**
from .forms import UserCreationForm

```
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect("my-login")

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, "register.html", context=context)
```

**register.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
.
.
.
<form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }} 
   
    # error is here
    {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
   
    {{ form.password1|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ form.password2|as_crispy_field }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Django 4.2.10

django-bootstrap4   24.1

django-crispy-forms 1.14.0

pillow              10.2.0

wheel               0.42.0

Comment: Your answer not related to the question. It does not fix the problem. @toyotaSupra

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
It was my fault in importing.

in Views.py I should import

`from . forms import CreateUserForm`

but I have imported:

`from .forms import UserCreationForm`